# Promoter base frequency matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

So I'm trying to write a program that gives me the frequency of a specific base in a promoter according to its position.
For example :
ACTGCTGATCGTAGC
GTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
For these, in seq[0],A=1 since in the first column, A appeared only once.
Here is the "sketch", or unfinished program if you will.

```
import numpy as np

def pfm(x, sequence):

a=0
t=0
c=0
g=0
y=np.array([[]])
for bases in sequence[z]:
    if sequence[z]==a:
        a+=1
    elif sequence[z]==t:
        t+=1
    elif sequence[z]==c:
        c+=1
    elif sequence[z]==g:
        g+=1
    return np.append(y,
    a=0
    t=0
    c=0
    g=0
    z+=1

x=input("Please enter the number of sequences you wish to analyze: ")
etc...
```

As you can see, I obviously didn't finish it due to a specific problem. I would like to append to the empty set, but I keep getting the error "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly" when I parts of it out in a shell. So I was wondering how can I append 4*1 matrices to the empty set. My idea is that each time I do so, I will set the base count back to 0 and keep appending their corresponding columns.
Thanks.

Comment: all your sequences have the same size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your sequences have all the same size :
for example :

```
['atatatg', 
 'atgcatg',
 'acggtaa', 
 'tagcgta']
```

you can do something like :

```
LoS=['atatatg', 'atgcatg','acggtaa', 'tagcgta']
a=[]
t=[]
g=[]
c=[]
for j in range(len(LoS[0])):
    a.append([i[j] for i in LoS].count('a'))
    t.append([i[j] for i in LoS].count('t'))
    g.append([i[j] for i in LoS].count('g'))
    c.append([i[j] for i in LoS].count('c'))

print "a", a
print "t", t
print "g", g
print "c", c
```

Will give you :

```
a [3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
t [1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0]
g [0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2]
c [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

you have 3 time 'a' in first position in all your sequence ,etc...

Comment: If I have really large sequences, and a lot of them, for some reason python ends up just counting all the a's, t's, g's, and c's instead of how many there are per column. How do I get past this?

Comment: I need to know how are organize your data to be able to help you... you read a file ? Data are in a list ? a list of list ? can you update your post with a sample of your data in the way it's organized ?